# Change the value of the filed of composite type using `Symbol` or `String` in Julia

Tags: julia

How can I change the value of the field of composite type using `Symbol` or `String`?

Example: If I have `MyType`,

```
type MyType
   x
end
mt=MyType(0)
```

I know I can change the value by `mt.x=1`.

However, how can I do the same thing using a variable `changed_fieldname = :x` or  `changed_fieldname = x`?

I don't want to directly write the name of the field as `mt.x=1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`setfield!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/base/#Base.setfield!):

```
julia> mt=MyType(0)
MyType(0)

julia> changed_fieldname = :x
       setfield!(mt, changed_fieldname, 1)
1

julia> mt
MyType(1)
```